# Oracle Form Personalization Calling Custom Procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am doing form personalization in HR module .my requirement is when the end-user is  trying to terminate than a procedure should get executed and check the condition if the is not met then it should display an error in the front end form

I am using this procedure:=

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE validate_terminate IS    
   u_id    NUMBER := fnd_global.user_id;    
   e_id    NUMBER;    
   p_id    NUMBER;    
   l_yes   VARCHAR2 (1);    
   null_found EXCEPTION;    
BEGIN    
   SELECT   EMPLOYEE_ID    
     INTO   e_id    
     FROM   fnd_user    
    WHERE   user_id = u_id;    

   SELECT   person_id    
     INTO   p_id    
     FROM   per_all_people_f    
    WHERE   person_id = e_id;    

   SELECT   'Y'    
     INTO   l_yes    
     FROM   DUAL    
    WHERE   EXISTS    
               (SELECT   'Y'
                  FROM   pa_expenditure_items_all paei,
                         pa_expenditures_all pae    
                 WHERE   paei.expenditure_id = pae.expenditure_id
                   AND pae.incurred_by_person_id = p_id    
                   AND paei.cost_distributed_flag = 'N');

   IF l_yes = NULL THEN    
      dbms_output.put_line ('USER CANNOT PERFORM TERMINATE');    
     RAISE null_found;    
   END IF;    
EXCEPTION    
   WHEN null_found THEN    
      dbms_output.put_line ('CONDITION IS NOT MET');    
      dbms_output.put_line ('CANNOT PROCESS TERMINATE');    
   WHEN no_data_found THEN    
      dbms_output.put_line ('CONDITION IS NOT MET');    
      dbms_output.put_line ('CANNOT PROCESS TERMINATE');    
END;
```

The procedure is working fine but I am unable to execute it in the front end

as I am doing these below are the screenshots

[front end from][1]

[ACTION tab image][2]

but the procedure is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

dbms_output.put_line is only in pl/sql visible if serveroutput is on.
You won't see these messages in oracle forms.

You should use `message` or an `alert` followed by

```
raise form_trigger_failure
```

Comment: nightfox79 can you please provide details about raise form_trigger_failure.

Comment: like I said, use function message and on the next line the command raise form_trigger_failure